# action Update() in Yii to update another model's update

Tags: mysql, yii, relational-database

I have the database like this

```
 === Invoice ===
 id
 customer_id (FK)
 description

 === Customer ===
 id
 firstname
 lastname
```

I have multimodel for both the form so that Cstomer table will be load in Invoice. So that I can easily access the two models from a single view. For that I have made relation in both models just like this
In Invoice model the realtion is like this

```
  public function relations()
  {
    return array(
    'customer'    =>  array(self::BELONGS_TO,'Customer','customer_id'),
    );
  }
```

In Customer Model the relation is like this

```
public function relations()
  {
    return array(
      'invoice' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Invoices','customer_id')
    );
  }
```

Everything is working fine.But when I am going for actionUpdate() in Invoice controller file there is Customer model is not defined. So I made it define like this

```
 public function actionView($id)
  {
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
      'customers'=>Customers::model()->findByPk(array('customer_id'=>$_GET['id']));
    ));
  }
```

It is showing as Undefined offset: 0. I want here in ('customer_id'=>$_GET['id']) the value of id so that I can easily show and update the values for each ids.
If I am giving the value like this

```
public function actionView($id)
  {
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$this->loadModel($id),
      'customers'=>Customers::model()->findByPk(28);
    ));
  }
```

It is easily showing the value from Customer id. So how to get those values?Any help and suggestions will be highly appriciable.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
public function actionView($id)
  {
    $model = $this->loadModel($id);
    $this->render('view',array(
      'model'=>$model,
      'customers'=>Customers::model()->findByPk($model->customer_id);
    ));
  }
```

Comment: Thank you @mazzucci for such a quick reply.That is not working.As you can see above the database customer table has a foreign key in the  Invoice table.So thats why I had put an array.In array what should be the condition so that it will be the same id in Invoice table and Customer table,or anything like findByAttributes...

Comment: then you should use `findAll` method instead of `findByPk`. Maybe this will be more helpful http://www.yiiframework.com/forum/index.php/topic/27840-create-relation-based-on-get-param/

Comment: So what do you think what should be the condition?

Comment: Try this `'customers'=>Customers::model()->findAll(array('customer_id'=>$_GET['id']))`

Comment: Actually no. Customers table don't have `customer_id` field. You should get the id of the custom from the invoice and then search by `pk` the customer.

Comment: Ya Customer don't have customer_id in it. Invoice has customer_id.So how to do it by findByPk()?